# Swift: Can I get information for an application which is not running?

Tags: swift, macos, bundle

I am writing an application which stores data about other applications. I can find the current front most application and its information easily enough:

```swift
let frontApp = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication!
```

and from there I can get:

```swift
let currentAppName = currentApp.localizedName ?? "Dunno"
let currentAppIcon = currentApp.icon
```

If the application is not in the foreground, I know I can iterate through other running applications:

```swift
let apps = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications
for app in apps as [NSRunningApplication] {
    print(app.localizedName ?? "whatever")
    print(app.bundleIdentifier ?? "bundle")
}
```

I would like to get the same information about a application which is not currently running, but for which I do have the bundle identifier. How can I get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, get the application's bundle using

```
let bundleURL = NSWorkspace.shared.urlForApplication(withBundleIdentifier: someBundleID)!
let bundle = Bundle(url: bundleURL)!
```

Once you have the bundle, you can get most of the things that you can get from a `NSRunningApplication`:

- `bundleIdentifier` you already know.
- `bundleURL` you just got with the code above.
- `executableArchitecture` is now `bundle.executableArchitectures`, with a plural. Because it's not running, you get all the architectures that it can be run on, rather than the specific architecture that it is running on.
- `executableURL` you can get with `bundle.executableURL`, no problems there.
- `launchDate`, `isFinishedLaunching`, `processIdentifier`, `ownsMenuBar` are nonsensical to get, since the application is not running.

Now we are left with `icon` and `localizedName`. The methods I propose for getting these are less reliable. To get `icon`, do

```
NSWorkspace.shared.icon(forFile: bundleURL.path)
```

I'm sure this produces the same result as `NSRunningApplication.icon` at least 99% of the time, but I'm not sure if there are edge cases...

To get `localizedName` is more unreliable. There are 2 ways, neither of which are good. Choose the one that fits your purpose the best

- `FileManager.default.displayName(atPath: bundleURL.path)` This gives you the localised name, but if the user renames the application, it will return the new name, rather than the bundle name
- Getting `CFBundleDisplayName` from the bundle's `localizedInfoDictionary`, falling back on `CFBundleName` and `infoDictionary`. This for some reason doesn't give the localised name, even though I said `localizedInfoDictionary`.

  ```
  let infoDict = (bundle.localizedInfoDictionary ?? bundle.infoDictionary)
  let localizedName = infoDict?["CFBundleDisplayName"] ?? infoDict?["CFBundleName"]
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That did the job. I did find, however, that the first option for getting the name did have `.app` on the end of the name. I know it’s not too hard to remove that.